# Codeigniter enabling profiler with output cache on

Tags: php, codeigniter, caching

i have problem with output benchmark profiler when also output cache is enabled,the benchmark does is not visualized in views.

I'm doing.

```
class  Home extends MX_Controller {


    function Home()
    {
           parent::__construct();

           $this->output->cache(20000);
           $this->output->enable_profiler(TRUE);
   }
```

how can i visualize the benchmark to see how faster is the page with cache on?

Comment: Do you have mark points?

Comment: @Damien Pirsy nope that was the problem :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order for the profiler to work you need to set markers, used as a start and end point to benchmark your application.
Because, quoting from the [manual](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/caching.html):

> Note: The Benchmark tag is not cached so you can still view your page
>   load speed when caching is enabled.

Wherever you want to start use (you don't need to initialize this class):

```
$this->benchmark->mark('starting_point');
```

And, when you want to end it:

```
$this->benchmark->mark('ending_point');
```

Then the result:

```
echo $this->benchmark->elapsed_time('starting_point', 'ending_point');
```

You can use as many as you want, just give them a different name of course.

Comment: and where i should set the benchmarkers? in view? don't think cause view is cached !? in controller?

Comment: Wherever you want, they work as is either in View,Controller or Model, so it's up to you. I usually put markers in controllers and output in view, but that's just me. Anyway, if any doubt, refer to the [benchmark](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/benchmark.html) page, it's pretty clear

Comment: Ok, I just saw you you already found it, good. Glad to have helped!